# PyOpenCL: how to create a local memory buffer?

Tags: python-2.7, opencl, pyopencl

Probably extremely simple question here, but I've been searching for it for hours with nothing to show for.

I have this piece of code, I'd like to have a 256-bit (8 uint32) bitstring_gpu as a localmemory pointer in the device:

```
def Get_Bitstring_GPU_Buffer(ctx, bitstring):
    bitstring_gpu = cl.Buffer(ctx, mem_flags.READ_ONLY | mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=bitstring)
return bitstring_gpu
```

This is later used on a kernel call:

```
prg.get_active_hard_locations_64bit(queue, (HARD_LOCATIONS,), None, memory_addresses_gpu.data, bitstring_gpu, distances_gpu.data, hash_table_gpu.data ).wait()
```

... and bitstring is just a random 256-bit bitstring (generated through sha256, then transformed into a numpy array.

```
def Get_Random_Bitstring():    
    bitstring = address_space_through_sha256_SDM.get_bitstring(str(random.randrange(2**32-1)))
return bitstring
```

How can I make bitstring_buf go to fast, local memory?

Related, but different question; here the buffer is being created inside the kernel...

[How to create variable sized __local memory in pyopencl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912968/how-to-create-variable-sized-local-memory-in-pyopencl)

Comment: You've mentioned `bitstring_buf`, however I see no mention of that in your code...

Comment: Bitstring is just a 256-bit random bitstring.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create variable sized \_\_local memory in pyopencl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912968/how-to-create-variable-sized-local-memory-in-pyopencl)

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question, but if you want your array placed in local memory - you do that entirely inside the kernel.  Your OpenCL code, not your Python code, is responsible for allocating and copying to local memory.

For example, this OpenCL code - inside a kernel - will create an array of 8 local uints and and copy one uint from global memory into the new local array.

```
__local uint my_local_array[8];

my_local_array[0] = my_global_array[0];
```

When you want your results back from local memory, you copy from local to global, then copy from global back to the host.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was under the impression that you could pass a buffer as __local; so, my idea is wrong?

Comment: Passing a `__local` parameter to your kernel is only required when the amount of local memory is not known at compile time and hence allocated dynamically.