# How do I allocate memory on a GPU memory using pyOpenCL?

Tags: python, pyopencl

I was looking some similar to malloc() which would allocate memory. I just want the memory to be reserved.

I want to fill up X amount of GBs/ MBs.

So far I have managed to query available local memory.

How do I fill up, say 80% of it?

Currently the code below is allocating the space on System Memory (RAM)

```
import pyopencl as cl # OpenCL - GPU computing interface
from pyopencl import device_info 
import numpy as np
import time
import sys

# Hardware devices
platforms = cl.get_platforms()

# getting GPUs
my_gpu_devices = [platforms[0].get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.GPU)[0]]
print(my_gpu_devices)

# Context set to GPU 0
ctx = cl.Context(devices = my_gpu_devices)

# Querying Local memory size
local_memory_size = my_gpu_devices[0].get_info(device_info.LOCAL_MEM_SIZE)

print("VRam size : ", local_memory_size)
# time.sleep(200)

flood_data = np.random.rand(256 ** 2).astype(np.int32)
print(sys.getsizeof(flood_data))

buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, 
                cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE, 
                size = (local_memory_size - 1000), 
                hostbuf = None
)

queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

for _ in range (0, 200000):
    cl.enqueue_fill_buffer(
                queue = queue, 
                mem = buf, 
                pattern = np.int32(0), 
                offset = 0, 
                size =  int(sys.getsizeof(np.int32) * 128)

    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyOpenCL: how to create a local memory buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271634/pyopencl-how-to-create-a-local-memory-buffer)

Comment: @Patol75 So memory allocation is actually done with the C code. But I have no idea how to deal with that.

Comment: I guess the best way to move forward is to read the [doc](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/). Might take a while, but will be worth the effort.